# How to install Booksim?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Linux and have a need to install Booksim 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have already downloaded .tar.gz package and extracted it.

STEP 1: sudo apt-get install LEX
STEP 2: sudo apt-get install YACC
STEP 3: ./booksim torus88
my MAKE FILE contains LEX and YACC files in the same directory.so no modifications were made.
but when i tried to run the example it shows no command found(eg: mesh command not found)

Could somebody help me how to install Booksim step by step, please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact command you are using and the complete error message. You will need to give the paths to the executable file and to the input file e.g. from the main `booksim2` directory, type `src/booksim runfiles/meshconfig`

Comment: :~$ cd Documents/booksim/trunk/src
:~/Documents/booksim/trunk/src$ make

make: 'booksim' is up to date.

:~/Documents/booksim/trunk/src$ ./booksim mesh88_lat

Could not open configuration file mesh88_lat

:~/Documents/booksim/trunk/src$ ./booksim traffic.cpp

Parse error on line 3 : syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to the installation of `booksim` - it's simply a matter of understanding the relationships between the locations of the files

```
src
├── allocators
├── arbiters
├── booksim
├── examples
│   ├── anynet
│   └── mesh88_lat
├── networks
├── power
└── routers
```

So from the `src` directory, you need to run

```
./booksim examples/mesh88_lat
```